# PyQt make error while compiling the source code

Tags: qt, makefile, installation, pyqt, configure

I want to install PyQt for Qt 4.7.4 and i downloaded the packages SIP and [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download) from riverbankcomputing.co.uk.

I configured and installed SIP successfully and configured PyQt successfully. But when i ran `make` in the terminal i got this error:

```
/home/user/Desktop/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.8.5/QtCore/sipQtCoreQThread.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* meth_QThread_currentThreadId(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:

/home/user/Desktop/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.8.5/QtCore/sipQtCoreQThread.cpp:325:50: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘long unsigned int’

/home/user/Desktop/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.8.5/QtCore/sipQtCoreQThread.cpp:325:50: error: initializing argument 1 of ‘PyObject* PyLong_FromUnsignedLong(long unsigned int)’

make[1]: *** [sipQtCoreQThread.o] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Desktop/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.8.5/QtCore'

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The full log is here: http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=176672&c=5376703

Can you help me fix this error, please? Thank you!

Comment: For what platform are you trying to compile PyQt ? Can't you use prebuilt binaries ? There might be a special PyQt version for Qt Embedded somewhere...

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 11.04. I'd like it for Qt 4.7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the build log, PyQt's configure script has found and is using the Simulator/embedded variant of Qt, and not the Desktop variant.

Try passing the path to *qmake* of the Desktop variant to the configure script:

```
python ./configure.py -q /home/user/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/gcc/bin/qmake
```

Comment: After executing i get:

Usage: python configure.py [opts] [macro=value] [macro+=value]
configure.py: error: '/home/user/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/gcc/bin/qmake' is not a file

Thank you for answering!

Comment: @John you should adapt the path to where qmake actually is (based on the log, it should at least be in a sub directory of /home/user/.QtSDK/Desktop).

Answer (score 0):

There are two choices

```
python ./configure.py -q /home/user/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/gcc/bin/qmake
```

or

```
python ./configure.py -q /home/user/.QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/bin/qmake
```

second will exit with some error code.

I'm trying first string right now.